# Direction to rotation angles in 3D?

Tags: opengl, math, 3d, vector-graphics

Suppose I have this chicken model who I want to constantly look towards the viewer (camera position), or more easily, towards the origin (0,0,0).
How do I calculate the angles for each axis so that I can rotate the object with them?

**Edit:**

Sorry if my question was too general. I'm still struggling with this though.
Let's say that the 3D model position is (x,y,z) in model space, and I want the model to "look" towards the origin.
My first thoughts were to begin to rotate around the x axis (rotate vertically):
Consider the yellow circle as the y plane.

[image]

So I tried the following code, which doesn't rotate the model at all.

```
glm::vec3 camPos = camera.GetPosition();
float value = camPos.y / glm::sqrt(glm::pow(camPos.x,2.0f) + glm::pow(camPos.y, 2.0f) + glm::pow(camPos.z, 2.0f));
float angle = glm::asin(value);
cow.SetModelMatrix(glm::translate(camPos - glm::vec3(0,0,1.5)) * //then translate so the cow will appear a little bit infront of the camera
                   glm::rotate(glm::radians(angle), glm::vec3(-1,0,0)) *//then rotate vertically by the angle
                   glm::scale(glm::vec3(0.1, 0.1, 0.1)) //first scale, cause the cow (i mean chicken) is too big
                   );
```

The camera starts at position (0, 0, 5), looking towards the negative z axis.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have not provided enough information for a good answer. Please give example values, as well as the sequence of rotations you use for orientations.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are describing, but I have a feeling it is called ["billboarding"](http://nehe.gamedev.net/article/billboarding_how_to/18011/).

Comment: It's because you're rotating the cow, not the chicken.

Comment: Try not to do it all in one statement. It makes it very hard to see the intermediate steps and understand what is going on.

Comment: What is the initial orientation of the chicken? Do you want to align the local x, y, or z axis to the line towards the origin? This information is still missing to fully answer here.

Comment: Okay I split it to different statements

Comment: "cow" is an instance of class Entity. Each entity stores a pointer to the actual vertices of its 3D model and a (model) transformation matrix. Then, in my "render" function, I call
`ModelMatrix = cow.GetModelMatrix();
program.SetUniform("ModelMatrix", ModelMatrix);
cow.Draw();`

Answer (score 0):

If the chicken is at the origin `c=(0,0,0)` and the camera is at `r=(x,y,z)` and ground is at `y=0`. Then what you want is a sequence of rotations to get the local `x` axis of the chicken pointed towards the camera.

First orient your `x` axis on the plane with a rotation about the vertical `y` axis with an angle `φ=-ATAN(z/x)` and then a rotation about the `z` axis with an angle `ψ=ATAN(y/√(x^2+z^2))`

This creates a 3×3 rotation matrix `E = ROT_Y(φ)*ROT_Z(ψ)`

```
    | x/d  -x*y/(d*√(x^2+z^2)) -z/√(x^2+z^2) |
E = | y/d    √(x^2+z^2)/d            0       |
    | z/d  -y*z/(d*√(x^2+z^2))  x/√(x^2+z^2) |
```

where `d=√(x^2+y^2+z^2)`. You see the local `x` axis (the first column of `E`) pointing towards `(x,y,z)`. Also the local `z` axis has no component on the vertical, so it always lies on the ground plane.

But this depend on the implementation, like if you need to keep the chicken `y` vertical (as opposed to keeping `z` in the ground plane) you will need a different set of rotations and angles. So to fully answer you need to provide more information.

Comment: I did edit my question, can you respond? Your case isn't what I'm looking for